# scipy optimization according to the experimental curve

Tags: python

Please tell me how to determine the unknown parameters in the calculated curve, using scipy optimization, having an experimental curve at the input. I need to determine the unknown parameters a, b, c (in the code below) from the calculated curve, so that the standard deviation functional is minimal

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from math import pi

def func(a,b,c):
    return -a/(2*np.tan(c*(pi/2)))+np.sqrt(b+(a**2)/(4*np.tan((c)*(pi/2))))  

file=experimental curve in .txt file
pd_file=pd.read_csv(file, sep="\s+",header=None,names=['frequence', 'y'],         
skiprows=1)
xdata=pd_file['frequence']
ydata=pd_file['y']
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=[0.6,1], maxfev=500000000)
print('popt',popt)
```

Comment: can you pls provide `experimental curve in .txt file`

Comment: unfortunately I don't know how to attach a text file here

Comment: usually people put it on a google drive or similar and post a link

Comment: let's try like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rbw8bUAEfMhl9-m3INhKI8ikmVCdShA5/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your functional form is suitable for fitting the data you have. After some experimentation may I suggest a different one:

```
def func2(x,b, d):
    return 0.2/ (1 + b * x + d * np.log(1+x))

file='chi_strich_strich_H0.txt'
pd_file=pd.read_csv(file, sep="\s+",header=None,names=['frequence', 'y'],         
skiprows=1)
xdata=pd_file['frequence']
ydata=pd_file['y']
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2, xdata, ydata, p0=[0,0], maxfev=500000000)
print('popt',popt)
yfit = func2(xdata,popt[0], popt[1])
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, '.', label = 'data')
plt.plot(xdata, yfit, '-', label = 'fit')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.show()
```

popt: `[ 1.84672386e-05 -7.69652828e-02]`

The fit is on this plot:
[image]

Comment: the formula to fit is specified in my code, and the formula for fitting should be such and only from it, it is necessary to determine the unknowns a , b , c; Unfortunately, the fitting option you suggested does not suit me. I saw how you can make a fitting in Origin using such a formula, but I would like to make the Origin algorithm in python

Comment: @MIKKIMOUSE well what can I say, the formula you have does not fit the data. Perhaps worth double checking it is indeed the one you want to use. . Specifically which of the variables represents `x`? I assumed it is `a` as it is the first one but perhaps it is some other one or, indeed, is missing

Comment: the original formula is the following :

Comment: the original formula is the following :
y1=a+b*(1-((sinh(c)*ln(x*const))/(cosh(c)*ln(x*const)+cos(0.5*c*pi)))
y2=b*((sin(0.5*c*pi))/(cosh(c)*ln(x*const)+cos(0.5*c*pi)))
after that the formula is made y2/y1 (mentioned in my first post) depending on the x

Comment: this formula does not look like the formula in your original question? More importantly, is `xconst` the value of x? Ie the one that corresponds to the first column of your  txt file?

Comment: yes, xconst=x*const is the value of x. Those. xconst matches first column of txt file